# Clearing UITableViewCells above section header

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a UITableView, like the diagram below:

```
Before scroll:
|         |
|         |
|         |  < Clear cell, showing view below table
|         |
|---------|
| section |  < Section header
|---------|
|    1    |
|    2    |
|    3    |
|    4    |
|    5    |


After scroll:
|         |
|         |
|    1    |  < Don't want to see these cells above the section
|    2    |
|---------|
| section |  < Section header
|---------|
|    5    |
|    6    |
```

I'm using a clear cell in the first section, because I want people to be able to scroll the table even from the top of the screen.

How can I make sure the cells above the section header are not visible?

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented this method to make my tableview to stop at cell 1 when scrolling up, maybe you can adapt it for your scenario.

```
int start;
int stop;

-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    NSArray *paths = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    @try{
    start = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] row];
    }
    @catch (NSException* NSRangeException) {
        NSLog(@"exception");
    }
}


    -(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

        NSArray *paths = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
        @try{
          stop = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] row];
        }
        @catch (NSException* NSRangeException) {
            NSLog(@"exception");
        }
        if(stop == 0 && start > 1){
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 animations:^{
                [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 44)];
            }];
        }

    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if(indexPath.row == 0){

                self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 44);

        }
    ......
    }
```

Comment: In Objective-C, the use of `@try` and `@catch` is a code smell: you're likely doing something wrong if you need them. In that case, accessing an array by index without checking the bounds first. Exceptions are terribly inefficient in Objective-C and have a lot of problems, so you should avoid them.

Comment: I agree with you, in my case it was really crashing the app sometimes, I put them as a workaround, until I'll understand why.